# Adding a values to a columns from a datagridview to a Excel the last column value is not getting add?

Tags: c#

[This is my excel sheet where last column value entered from datagrid is not getting added]

code:
 private void writeExcelFileToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            // creating new WorkBook within Excel application
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            // creating new Excelsheet in workbook
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
            // see the excel sheet behind the program
            app.Visible = true;
            // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.
            // store its reference to worksheet
            worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
            worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
            // changing the name of active sheet

```
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
        // storing header part in Excel  
        for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        //This Filter property is used to filter the type of files to be save 
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xlsx";
        //This is used to open the savedialog window
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            app.Workbooks[1].SaveCopyAs(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            MessageBox.Show("Excel Saved", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //TextBoxForMultipleSelctionOfExcel.Text = "";
        }
        //Closing the Workbook
        for (int i = 1; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
        {
            app.Workbooks[i].Close(0);
        }
        //Quiting the Excel Application
        app.Quit();
```

Comment: Check your for loops. You did Rows.Count -1 but didn't do that to the Columns.Count.

Comment: I had check it for loops are correct. The problem is when i debug the code i see that its not getting the value ........worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();